How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{n}$?
I wonder how to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{inx}}{n}$. I know for $|z|< 1$, we have $-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$, and I want to take $z=e^{ix}$, but $|e^{ix}|=1$ does not satisfy the condition. Can anyone give some help?

Show that your series converges if $x\neq0 \bmod 2\pi$ and use Abel's theorem on power series (complex version).

Thanks, I get it.
